# Unexpected border in Composables. Border shows even if border width is Zero.?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have created a custom composable to show text inside a Box. Even if I specified border width as Zero with modifier, composable still show a thin border. Any idea why composable (or modifier) behaves this way?

**Composable Code**

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TextBox(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    backgroundColor: Color = Color.Yellow,
    borderWidth: Dp = 0.dp,
    borderColor: Color = Color.Black
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .background(backgroundColor)
            .border(
                width = borderWidth,
                color = borderColor
            ),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(text = "EXPLORE")
    }
}
```

**Preview Code**

```kotlin
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun TextBoxPreview() {
    TextBox(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(75.dp)
            .padding(16.dp),
        backgroundColor = Color.Yellow,
        borderWidth = 0.dp,
        borderColor = Color.Black
    )
}
```

**Output Preview**

[image: Output Preview from Peview panel]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Border.kt`, we can see this method,

```
fun Modifier.border(width: Dp, brush: Brush, shape: Shape): Modifier = composed(
    // irrelevant code
    val hasValidBorderParams = width.toPx() >= 0f && size.minDimension > 0f
    if (!hasValidBorderParams) {
        drawContentWithoutBorder()
    } else {
    val strokeWidthPx = min(
        if (width == Dp.Hairline) 1f else ceil(width.toPx()),
        ceil(size.minDimension / 2)
    )
    // irrelevant code
    }
    // irrelevant code
}
```

And for `Dp.Hairline`.

```
val Hairline = Dp(value = 0f)
```

So, providing a border width of `0.dp` creates a border of `1px`.

---

If we want to hide the border conditionally,
we can use a `Transparent` color for the border based on width.

```
.border(
    width = borderWidth,
    color = if (borderWidth == 0.dp) {
        Transparent
    } else {
        borderColor
    },
),
```